# Deserialize a Vec of values into a struct by implementing serde `Deserializer`

Tags: serialization, rust, serde

I have a data format using custom enum of values. From the database I receive a `Vec<MyVal>`. I want to convert this to a struct (and fail if it doesn't work). I want to use serde because after processing I want to return the API response as a json, and serde makes this super easy.

[Playground link for the example](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=26f5149ee6297ad954b6e974f0cc63c5)

```rust
enum MyVal {
  Bool(bool),
  Text(String)
}

#[derive(Serialize, Deserialize)]
struct User {
  name: String,
  registered: bool
}
```

The challenge is with converting the data format into the serde data model. For this I can implement a `Deserializer` and implement the `visit_seq` method i.e. visit the `Vec<MyVal>` as if it were a sequence and return the values one by one. The visitor for `User` can consume the visited values to build the `struct User`.

However I'm not able to figure out how to convert the `Vec` into something `visitor_seq` can consume. Here's some sample code.

```rust
struct MyWrapper(Vec<MyVal>);

impl<'de> Deserializer<'de> for MyWrapper {
    type Error = de::value::Error;

    // skip unncessary

    fn deserialize_seq<V>(self, visitor: V) -> Result<V::Value, Self::Error>
    where
        V: serde::de::Visitor<'de>,
    {
        let convert_myval = move |myval: &MyVal| match myval {
            MyVal::Bool(b) => visitor.visit_bool(*b),
            MyVal::Text(s) => visitor.visit_string(s.clone())
        };

        // now I have a vec of serde values
        let rec_vec: Vec<Result<V::Value, Self::Error>> =
            self.0.iter().map(|myval| convert_myval(myval)).collect();
        // giving error!!
        visitor.visit_seq(rec_vec.into_iter())
    }
}
```

The error is

```rust
92   |         visitor.visit_seq(rec_vec.into_iter())
     |                 --------- ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ the trait `SeqAccess<'de>` is not implemented for `std::vec::IntoIter<Result<<V as Visitor<'de>>::Value, _::_serde::de::value::Error>>`
     |                 |
     |                 required by a bound introduced by this call
```

So I looked into [SeqAccess](https://docs.serde.rs/serde/de/trait.SeqAccess.html#impl-SeqAccess%3C%27de%3E-1) and it has an implementor that requires that whatever is passed to it implement the `Iterator` trait. But I thought I had that covered, because `vec.into_iter` returns an `IntoIter`, a consuming iterator which does implement the `Iterator` trait.

So I'm completely lost as to what's going wrong here. Surely there must be a way to visit a `Vec<Result<Value, Error>>` as a seq?

Comment: It might be nice to show an example of an input value (e.g. in JSON, even if that's not your actual input format) you want to deserialize, and a playground link that directly reproduces your problem (What's a `Field`?). Btw: your `struct` definitions aren't valid Rust.

Comment: Does `struct MyWrapper(#[serde(flatten)] Vec<MyVal>);` allow `Deserialize` to be derived?

Comment: I've fixed the names and added a playground link. Sadly flatten won't work because `MyVal` is actually imported from different crate and it does not derive `Deserialize`. That is why I'm doing the mapping in `convert_myval` closure.

Comment: It turns out that newtypes -- tuple structs with one field -- (de)serialize directly to/from the contained value. You can't implement (De)serialize for a type outside your crate, but you can create your own newtype wrapping a `Vec<String>`, derive `Deserialize` for it, and then implement `From<MyNewtype>` for `MyWrapper`

Comment: Hmm yes that is one way to do it, I'll try it out. Still I'd love to understand what's going wrong here, from a learning perspective.

Comment: "`MyVal` is actually imported from different crate and it does not derive `Deserialize`" this statement makes me very confused about what you're trying to do. If `MyVal` were to implement `Deserialize`, it would be something that is deserialized /into/. But your current code implements it as something to be deserialized /from/, as if `MyVal` were some binary data which you're trying to deserialize into yet another struct or value. So, which is it? (In case you're just troubled by `MyVal` not being `Deserialize`: [remote-derive](https://serde.rs/remote-derive.html).)

Comment: In case you do actually want to treat `Vec<MyVal>` as a "data format" to be deserialized from, you'll need two deserializers, one for `Vec<MyVal>`, and another for `MyVal` (resp. their wrappers). [Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=f366ee85aeb0090626f4a60c96d5ace8) (I also don't think it's ok to reuse the visitor from `deserialize_seq` and call `visit_bool`, etc. on it.)

Comment: You should put this in the answer section because this does solve the problem. The key insight for me here is that every intermediate value in the de-serialization process must have a struct/wrapper that implements `IntoDeserializer`. I thought I could kind off skip that by converting them in the same visit.

Comment: Will do, but for context… what are you actually trying to deserialize `Vec<MyVal>` into? Are you making a library and having your user provide that? If not, this solution seems like a lot of overkill.

Comment: Yes I guess calling it a library is best. I'm trying to generically deserialize a struct from [aws-sdk-rust](https://docs.rs/aws-sdk-rdsdata/latest/aws_sdk_rdsdata/model/enum.Field.html). The rds database format currently does not implement serde so manipulating query results becomes a challenge.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Preface: The question wants to treat a Rust data structure `Vec<MyData>` like a serialized piece of data (e.g.: like a JSON string) and allow deserializing that into any other Rust data structure that implements `Deserialize`. This is a quite unusual, but not without precedent. And since the `MyVal`s are actually pieces of data with various types which get returned from a database access crate, this approach does make sense.

The main problem with the code in the question is that it tries to deserialize two different data structures (`MyWrapper<Vec<MyVal>>` and `MyVal`) with a single `Deserializer`. The obvious way out is to define a second `struct MyValWrapper(MyVal)` and implement `Deserializer` for it:

```rust
struct MyValWrapper(MyVal);
impl<'de> Deserializer<'de> for MyValWrapper {
    type Error = de::value::Error;

    fn deserialize_any<V>(self, visitor: V) -> Result<V::Value, Self::Error>
    where
        V: de::Visitor<'de>,
    {
        match self.0 {
            MyVal::Bool(b) => visitor.visit_bool(b),
            MyVal::Text(s) => visitor.visit_string(s.clone()),
        }
    }

    // Maybe you should call deserialize_any from all other deserialize_* functions to get a passable error message, e.g.:
    forward_to_deserialize_any! {
        bool i8 i16 i32 i64 i128 u8 u16 u32 u64 u128 f32 f64 char str string
        bytes byte_buf option unit unit_struct newtype_struct seq tuple
        tuple_struct map struct enum identifier ignored_any
    }
    // Though maybe you want to handle deserialize_enum differently...
}
```

`MyValWrapper` now can deserialize a `MyVal`. To use `MyValWrapper` to deserialize a `Vec` of `MyVal`s, the `serde::value::SeqDeserializer` adapter is convenient, it can turn an iterator of (`Into`)`Deserializer` into a sequence `Deserializer`:

```rust
let data: Vec<MyData> = …;
// Vec deserialization snippet
let mut sd = SeqDeserializer::new(data.into_iter().map(|myval| MyValWrapper(myval)));
let res = visitor.visit_seq(&mut sd)?;
sd.end()?;
Ok(res)
```

For some reason, `SeqDeserializer` requires the iterator items to be `IntoDeserializer`, but no `impl<T: IntoDeserializer> Deserializer for T` exists, so we need to make sure that `MyValWrapper` is not only a `Deserializer` but trivially also an `IntoDeserializer`:

```
impl<'de> IntoDeserializer<'de> for MyValWrapper {
    type Deserializer = MyValWrapper;
    fn into_deserializer(self) -> Self::Deserializer {
        self
    }
}
```

Finally, you need to `impl Deserializer for MyWrapper` (you can use the "Vec deserialization snippet" for that) — if you do actually need `Deserializer` to be implemented, which I suspect you don't: the `SeqDeserializer` already implements `Deserializer`, and it is a wrapper struct (just as `MyWrapper` is a wrapper struct). Especially, if your final goal is having a function like

```rust
fn turn_bad_myvals_into_good_T<T: DeserializeOwned>(v: Vec<MyVal>) -> T {
    T::deserialize(SeqDeserializer::new(
        v.into_iter().map(|myval| MyValWrapper(myval)),
    ))
}
```

then you entirely don't need `MyWrapper`.